# What is the error called when spaces are placed incorrectly?

Tags: orthography, errors, spacing

> He went home , but he forgot his phone .He returned to get it .
>
> ```
>              ^                       ^                   ^
> ```

These are some examples, which nowadays get autocorrected by word automatically, but I used to see them  a lot. Sadly (or thankfully) Stackexchange also autocorrects multiple consecutive spaces, so I could not show those in the example.

Comment: Multiple consecutive spaces are not necessarily an error. They are  unfashionable nowadays, but they have been used in the past in good typography. See this blog post: http://www.heracliteanriver.com/?p=324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Typographical error](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/typographical+error) is

> a mistake in printing, typesetting, or typing, especially one caused
>   by **striking an incorrect key** on a keyboard.

[Historical Examples](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/typographical-error)

> Page 34: The typographical error "w ash" was changed to "wash."

[American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition and Dictionary.com]